# Iron Sonic? Can’t find character or name

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog-series

I know about [Metal Sonic](http://info.sonicretro.org/images/5/5d/Sonicchannel_metal.png); it’s not who I’m talking about.

I remember in the first 2D games seeing another Sonic-like enemy with a metallic appearance, coloured grey. Unlike Metal Sonic, that character really looked like Sonic, shape-wise (big head and all).

I periodically search for it and sometimes I even find it in an old blurry screenshot, but never seem to retain its name. Any help in finding out who it is?

Comment: [Meta Discussion](//meta.arqade.com/q/10214/28182) about this question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm fairly sure it's [Mecha Sonic](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Mecha_Sonic_%28Death_Egg_Zone%29).

He appears in Sonic 2.

Here is an image of him in-game:

[image]

Comment: Other places I remember in the past listed him as Silver Sonic.